# SCHEME | native sort function complexity

Tags: sorting, scheme, runtime, time-complexity, racket

I was looking around for an answer but couldn't find any, not even in the SCHEME manuals and so...
I was wondering what is the run-time complexity of the *native* sort function implemented in scheme (in the basic package).
I've heard rumors it's O(n log n) or maybe O(n<sup>2</sup>), but non confirmed to be 100% true.

Also I would like to hear what's the sorting algorithm being used there.

Thanks!

Comment: `list-sort` is normally implemented as a merge sort as it needs to be stable as required by the spec (R6RS). This is `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: [easy enough to measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

leppie's answer is basically a complete answer.

Short answer: it depends on the implementation, but R6RS requires this sort to be stable, and it's therefore likely to be mergesort.

What Scheme are you using?

Comment: The tag mentions racket, but I doubt it would be any different.

Comment: Thx guys! Im using standard Racket

Answer (score 2):

#### GNU MIT Scheme

GNU MIT Scheme [implements two sort algorithms](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Miscellaneous-List-Operations.html#index-sort-1297):

- `merge-sort`
- `quick-sort`

Properly implemented each will run in O(n log n) time. This is the optimum time for any comparison sort algorithm. The `sort` procedure is an alias for `merge-sort`. Likewise, its mutable counterpart `sort!` is an alias for the mutable `merge-sort!`.

So why have `quick-sort` at all? The advantage of `quick-sort` is that sorting can be done in place when mutation is allowed. `quick-sort!` could be implemented to not require any additional memory beyond that allocated for the input vector: It can be implemented to require **exactly** *n* space, not O(n) space. This is not such a big deal on today's desktop computers, but matters when resources are limited.

C.A. Hoare's [orginal paper](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/5/1/10.full.pdf) describing quicksort.

#### Racket

According to the [source](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/2881b605361afacd98755c746ac2ac250e49b965/racket/collects/racket/private/sort.rkt), `#lang racket` uses a "[Fast mergesort implementation based on half-copying merge algorithm](http://kicia.ift.uni.wroc.pl/algorytmy/mergesortpaper.pdf)", by Cezary Juszczak.

Comment: Quicksort (implemented carefully) also requires fewer *expected* comparisons than merge sort.

Comment: @dfeuer MergeSort has O(n log n) worst case time complexity. The worst case for QuickSort has a worst case time complexity of O(n^2). Statistically, QuickSort will work in average case O(n log n) by randomizing pivot selection and above some size n the overhead of psuedo-random number generation and the tiny possibility of worst case performance are obviously worth it. But the rationale for letting the programmer choose their tradeoffs certainly is not unreasonable.

Comment: I completely agree that offering multiple choices is good, and also that different choices are better in different circumstances. My point was that being able to sort in place is not the only (or even primary) advantage of quicksort. In-place heapsort is also quite common (and some implementations are very efficient), and (not really practical) in-place merge sorts also exist. Heap sorts and (I think especially) merge sorts also can play very well with parallelism and cache hierarchies.

Comment: Where truly randomized quicksort actually beats all known deterministic algorithms is on worst-case expected comparison counts (i.e., expected comparison count for worst case input).